# R: Print a string of different length below each other and fill rest with spaces

Tags: r, printing

My problem is the following: I need to write my own print function and the output should be saved to a textfile and look very similiar to a table.

Basically my structure is this:

```
Description                                              Symbol       Rank
```

I've did this with:

```
paste("Description                                              Symbol       Rank", "\n",sep="")
```

Now you can guess my problem. Some Symbol descriptions are 10 letters long, some are 20 etc. That's why my paste function for these rows cannot be that simple. How do I need to program this to fill lets say for a 20 letter long string the remaining 10 with an empty space, whereas for a 10 letter string I fill the remaining 20 with an empty space?

Comment: Why does it need to be stretched out like that?  As longer strings are added, the table should naturally widen.

Comment: Hmm I need a defined with for this table. These textfiles will be included in word files. And I need to format it like that :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paste0(yourstring,paste0(rep(" ",20-nchar(yourstring)),collapse = ""))
```

this should help... I think

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with `str_pad`

```
> x <- c("Description", "Symbol", "Rank")
> library(stringr)
> str_pad(x, 20)
# [1] "         Description" "              Symbol" "                Rank"
> str_pad(x, 20, side = "right")
# [1] "Description         " "Symbol              " "Rank                "
> c(str_pad(x[1], 20, "right"), str_pad(x[2], 20), x[3])
# [1] "Description         " "              Symbol" "Rank"
```

Answer (score 1):

Third solution is the classic `sprintf`:

```
> x <- c("Description", "Symbol", "Rank")
> sprintf("%20s",x)
[1] "         Description" "              Symbol" "                Rank"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `formatC`

```
 formatC(x, width=-20)
 #[1] "Description         " "Symbol              " "Rank                "
```